# "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, odata

I have 2 POCO classes -- Contact and TrainingSeminar -- that joined in a many-to-many relationship using EF5

In the Contacts odata controller, I want to be able to return the TrainingSeminars that a contact is registered for...so I have the following controller method

```
public IQueryable<TrainingSeminar> GetTrainingSeminars([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var contact = _context.Contacts.Find(key);
    var seminars = contact.TrainingSeminars.ToList();
    return seminars as IQueryable<TrainingSeminar>;
}
```

When I debug in Visual Studio, the return object "seminars" has 2 items but I get the following error in Fiddler:

> "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json...."message":"Cannot serialize a null 'feed'

Answer (score 4):

From your code, `seminars` is a `List<T>` and hence the last line

```
return seminars as IQueryable<TrainingSeminar>;
```

would always be null as `List<T>` does not implement `IQueryable<T>`. You should be using,

```
return seminars.AsQueryable();
```

instead.